# Non-Expiring password on Linux server

Tags: linux, password

I'd like to set up an account on a linux server and make the account's password never expire. I'm having difficulties figuring it out with the `passwd` man page.  Could someone please help me out?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To maximize password expiration:

```
passwd -x 99999 username
```

To disable account expiration:

```
usermod -e '' username
```

To do both with chage:

```
chage -E -1 -M -1 username
```

To set the system defaults, look at /etc/default/useradd

Answer (score 5):

Use chage command:

```
chage -M -1 USERNAME
```

Answer (score 2):

## Solaris/SunOS:

**Turn off aging while allowing user to retain current password**

```
passwd -x -1 username
```

**Force user to change password at next login, and then turn off aging**

```
passwd -x 0 username
```

(Hopefully this helps someone out)

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-1387/6jam6929e/index.html#a08paswd-89198

Answer (score 0):

You want the `chage` command you just set the account minimum password to a rediculously long time like 9999999999 days.

here is a very good howto - http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/setting-off-password-aging-expiration.html

Comment: `chage` has an explicit value for this behavior. See bindbn's answer for example.

Answer (score 0):

The complete command to mitigate any other previous configurations is the following:

```
chage -E -1 -M -1 -I -1 username
```

Answer (score 0):

**AIX: Non expiring password**

Changing user history size

```
chuser histsize=0 <userid>
```

change the users password

```
passwd <userid>
```

Clear flags that tells the OS to reset password on login (after password reset)

```
pwdadm -c <userid>
```

If you do not want to cause any commotion by editing your user history size you can use the following command to change the security file to say that the last time you reset your password is always today's date. You can export this in your `.profile` file so it runs every time you log in as well.

```
chsec -f /etc/security/passwd -s <userid> -a lastupdate=`date +%s`
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full example of chage command (Change age) about Linux expiration password: Completely disable password expiration and account:

Parameters command chage :

```
-m 0 : Minimum number of days for the password change.
-M 99999 : Maximum number of days a password change.
-I -1 : We set: "Password inactive" never.
-E -1 : We set: "Expires Account" never.
```

The example username is: sysadmit

```
[root@linux1~] # chage -m 0 -M 99999 -I -1 -1 -E sysadmit

[root@linux1~] # chage --list sysadmit
Last password change: July 15, 2017 
Password expires: never 
Password inactive: never 
Account expires: never 
Minimum number of days Between password change: 0 
Maximum number of days Between password change: 99999
Number of days of warning before Expires password 7
```

Extracted from: http://www.sysadmit.com/2017/11/linux-caducidad-contrasena.html